# Get C-like speed in Python with ctypes, pass and return numpy array

Tags: python, c, arrays, ctypes

I have a speed relevant task and as far as I see it's not possible to use numpy to get C-like speed. So I want to implement a function in C and call it in my python script. I want to pass a (numpy) array to the C function and return an array from this function back to python.

The right solution for this should be to compile my C function and use ctypes to handle it in my python script. But I don't really know how to get it together. Because it's quiet a big array I want to pass and return it should somehow use pointer and don't make new copys every time.

```py
#define/read in numpy array in python
arr = np.zeros(shape=(100,100))

# define/compile this function in C
def fun(arr):
    #do some stuff, make new arr2
    return(arr2)

arr2 = mylib.fun(arr)
#use arr2 in python
```

Also my knowledge of C is kind of poor. The arr in the example should be a float, the return array arr2 could be an integer.

Comment: "Also my knowledge of C is kind of poor" - then things will probably go much smoother if you use Cython or Numba.

Comment: The function I want to implement in C is not that difficult. That's not the problem. But the wrapper and datatypes of that arrays.

Comment: Related: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/215235/133688

Comment: Use `arr.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.c_voidp)` to get a pointer that you can pass into your C-function. For the return array, I'd recommend pre-allocating that on the Python side, too, and passing it as a second argument in the same manner. This should avoid most memory management problems...

Comment: Are you sure that it would be faster in *C*? *NumPy* is also written in *C* and has vectorized operations just for speed.

Comment: @Jeronimo I think that's a good idea. But how would I pass the pointer to the C-function so that I can use arr[i][j] like arithmetic in the function? As I understand if it's a normal pointer to the arr[0]-element of the array. So do I have to do the arithemtic myself then?

Comment: Yes, the indexing is basically 1D then and you have to transform coordinates yourself.

Comment: I still have some problems to pass the pointer. If I define the pointer as you statet `test = arr.ctypes.data_as(ctypes.c_voidp)`. I would grab this pointer in the C function like: `void fun(void *test) { return *test[index]+1 }`. Is that right? Or do I have to define the datatype or something in the C-function again? (for an example of a C function returning some element of the array plus one)